# Ruby on rails - How to limit user to 1 entry per competition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

---

I'm building an app with the Models **User** (Devise), **Competition** & **Entry**.

An Entry belongs_to a Competition & a User.
Users may create many Entries (and therefore enter many Competitions) **BUT only one entry per competition.** (with validation) and also a method to display message if already competition already entered (eg. "You have already entered this competition").

I'm new to rails, and for the life of me can't figure out how this logic look like in code. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can validate the uniqueness of the pair (user_id, competition_id) in the Entry model

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :competition_id}, 
    :message => 'You have already entered this competition'
end
```

You may have to implement some logic to display the error message.

Comment: this looks great! I've just updated question, is there a way to check & display a message like, "You've already entered this competition" that I can display instead of a create new link? Thank you for a great answer though!